# I want to create a shell script wherein each project has set of instructions

Tags: command-line, scripts, groups, community

I want to create a shell script wherein each project has set of instructions which includes setting  different groups to setup for every different clearcase view.

I am facing difficulty as the setview and newgrp both create a subshell of its own and getting exited from the script.

I want help in having any alternate idea or how to solve this problem. I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try a structure like below to process on a variable depending on what is set, it is called a `case` statement. I use this to correct to the aspect ratio needed in video files, I show you the 4:3 section of it.

```
# File processing according to extension found
        case $EXTENSION in 
            
            mkv)

                # Use ffmpeg to correct aspect ratio
                ~/Bin/ffmpeg -i "$i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -aspect 4:3  "newfiles/$NAME.mkv"

                # Use mkvmerge to get rid of many English ffmpeg leaves in the Metadata
                ~/Bin/mkvmerge --no-subtitles "newfiles/$NAME.mkv" -o "newfiles/$NAME"

                # remove no longer needed newly created by ffmpeg file 
                rm "newfiles/$NAME.mkv"

                # Delete title (movie name) if any
                ~/Bin/mkvpropedit "newfiles/$NAME" -d title
            ;;
            
            m4v)

                # Use ffmpeg to correct aspect ratio
                ~/Bin/ffmpeg -i "$i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -aspect 4:3  "newfiles/$NAME"
            ;;
            
            mp4)

                # Use ffmpeg to correct aspect ratio
                ~/Bin/ffmpeg -i "$i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -aspect 4:3  "newfiles/$NAME"
            ;;
            
            avi)

                # Use ffmpeg to correct aspect ratio
                ~/Bin/ffmpeg -i "$i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -aspect 4:3  "newfiles/$NAME"
            ;;
            
            # no mkv, mp4, avi or m4v file found
            *) echo "$NAME is not a media file."
        
        esac
```

Comment: the following are the set of commands i am want in the script , but after the setview the script is existing . 

read -p "enter view name " $VIEW_NAME

cleartool  setview $VIEW_NAME

newgrp ulma